# Import locations from JSON file to use on my Google maps

Tags: javascript, json, html

Im new to this forum, and I would love to get your help. I have created my own html5 page with Google maps using API key provided by google (My code is below), the code works good with a central marker placed and it loads when I go in to the page, perfekt!

On the other hand I have a JSON that contains a lot of data, including a lot of locations. I want to import this into my page so I can get these location with markers on my map. Could some one help me? I have googled anywhere but this seems to a little bit confusing to me..

Anyways, here is my html code with Google api, very easy and simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 600px;
        width: 800px;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>



    <h3>Map over Oslo </h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var Oslo = {lat: 59.911491, lng: 10.757933};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: Oslo
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: Oslo,
          map: map
        });




      }
    </script>


    <div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    </div>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would love if somebody could help me import these locations from the JSON file I have, if interested, I could send this JSON file to your mail :)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using any libraries or frameworks?

Comment: No. Only the google maps API, and I have all this code inside my index.php file.

Comment: Where is the JSON file located? local or remote?

Comment: I have the JSON file local, at the same folder as my HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/urlOrPathToFile', true);

    request.onload = function() {
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // Success!
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
// Now that the JSON is in the DOM and parsed, create your map markers in a loop through the locations
      } else {
        // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

      }
    };

    request.onerror = function() {
      // There was a connection error of some sort
    };

    request.send();
```

Comment: I have made changes to my code where the JSON file is stored on my github. My code looks fine now the only error message i get is:

"  Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vlori2k/chargers/master/chargers.json' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.  "

Comment: console.log the request inside the "onerror" function

Answer (score 0):

I have now finished the code and it works perfectly! One of the things I did was to turn the json file into a js file and also change my for each loop in my index.php file and now it works!

Here is my index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var map;


    function initMap() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.911491,10.757933),

        });


        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'chargers.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }


    window.eqfeed = function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.chargerstations.length; i++){
            //i++;
            var coords = results.chargerstations[i].csmd.Position;
            //coords ="(123123, 123123)"
            coords = coords.replace('(', '');
            coords = coords.replace(')', '');
            coords = coords.split(",");

            var destenasjon = results.chargerstations[i].csmd.City;
            console.log("PPP",destenasjon);

            console.log(coords);
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]);
            if(destenasjon === 'OSLO'){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
                });

            }else{
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map
                });
            }


        }
    }


</script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```